# Swift3 - First Letter of Search Crashing Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am getting this error when the first line of my "else" block runs:

> unable to dequeue a cell with indentifier PhoneCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

So, the initial table is loading just fine, but when you try to do a search this exception is thrown.  This only started happening after I went to a custom cell.  Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath function for the table that is crashing.  Any idea what's going on?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if tableView == self.tableView{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhoneCell", for: indexPath) as! PhoneSearchResultTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = phones[indexPath.row].name.value
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = phones[indexPath.row].descriptionText.value
        cell.modelLabel.text = phones[indexPath.row].model.value
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = self.resultsController.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhoneCell", for: indexPath) as! PhoneSearchResultTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = filteredPhones[indexPath.row].name.value
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = filteredPhones[indexPath.row].descriptionText.value
        cell.modelLabel.text = filteredPhones[indexPath.row].model.value
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register the "PhoneCell" identifier with the table view in the resultsController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UITableViewController` does not have either a prototype cell in it's storyboard for you `"PhoneCell"` or if you are doing it programmatically you did not register the class for the cell identifier you are calling.

Try adding this in your `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` or somewhere before you instantiate your `UITableView`:

```
self.resultsController.tableView.register(PhoneSearchResultTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PhoneCell")
```

Comment: @GED125 sure thing Bub.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `UITableViewController` rather than a separate `UITableView`. If you created that custom cell as a prototype cell in IB, then make sure that the reuse identifier is set the same in the code and in the IB.

`UITableViewController` automatically registers the prototype cells.

However, if you start using `UITableView` separately, then you need to call `.register` method with either `UINib` or class of your custom cells.